# Python 3.4 - Simple greeting program

Tags: python, python-3.4

Python amateur here again... I'm making a simple greeting program. In the following function the user is to enter their gender. I want it so that the user can enter M for Male or F for female, so it's simple. So I've used the following code:

```
def genderFunction(firstName, fullName):
    print("%s, what is your gender?"%firstName)
    choice = input("Enter 'M' for Male or 'F' for Female\n")
```

What I want it to then do is from the M or F, create a new variable called 'gender' and either make it Male or Female. I'm unsure how to do this from the M/F input. Can anyone help? Please remember I'm new to this stuff. I tried it by doing this:

```
def genderFunction(firstName, fullName):
    print("%s, what is your gender?"%firstName)
    choice = input("Enter 'M' for Male or 'F' for Female\n")
    if(choice.upper() == "M"):
      gender = Male
```

However it didn't like this, which I knew it wouldn't, but it was worth a try.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do you want separate *class* objects of type **Male** and **Female**?

Comment: @KenHampson sorry for the slow response, a solution has already been found, but thank you for taking the time to read the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `Male` needs to be enclosed with quotes so that it becomes a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

   ```
   gender = "Male"
   ```

   Otherwise, a `NameError` will be raised because `Male` is undefined.
2. The name `choice` is undefined because you named the input `genderInput`.

Here is what your code should be:

```
def genderFunction(firstName, fullName):
    print("%s, what is your gender?"%firstName)
    genderInput = input("Enter 'M' for Male or 'F' for Female\n").upper()
    if genderInput == "M":
        gender = "Male"
    elif genderInput == "F":
        gender= "Female"
```

You'll notice too that I called `str.upper` at the end of the line that gets the input.  This saves you from having to call it once per if-statement.

Comment: Just realised my silly mistake. I've already made one of those on here when asking a question. I probably shouldn't try coding at 12 am... Thanks very much for pointing out my error! Also, in relation to the genderInput, I had changed it to choice after I had realised what I had done from my draft, but instead of copying my updated version, I copied my draft version. :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing `choice = input("Enter 'M' for Male or 'F' for Female\n)` you can put it into gender right away, like so: `gender = input("Enter 'M' for Male or 'F' for Female\n)`

then if you want to check if the user is, male for example, you might do something like:

```
if gender == 'M':
    #do stuff here
```

it doesn't really matter what you call `gender`, you could leave it as `choice` if you wanted. it's just easier to read and understand if you have it as `gender`.